# How to fix "failed to open stream" error in Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to upload image file to server. And I have failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections" error in "move_uploaded_file"
function. How can I fix it?

```
$image_src = $_FILES['ex_image']['tmp_name'];
$src = asset('assets/images/excavator/'.$title.'.png');
move_uploaded_file($image_src,$src);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `base_path()` method. This method returns the fully qualified path to the project root:

```
if ($request->hasFile('ex_image')) {
    $destinationPath = base_path().'/assets/images/excavator/';
    $file = $request->ex_image;
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
}
```

and if you want to return the `public` directory then use:

```
$destinationPath = public_path().'/assets/images/excavator/';
```